Masses of $SU(2)$ gauge bosons
I'm currently learning quantum field theory and I'm wondering one thing.The way I understood it is that in the $SU(2)$ Yang-Mills theory, all gauge bosons have the same mass due to the spontaneous symmetry breaking of the Higgs mechanism. In this theory, the gauge boson acquires a mass through interaction with the Higgs field. The Higgs field has a certain vacuum expectation value, which is not symmetric under $SU(2)$ transformations. As a result, the symmetry is broken and the gauge bosons, which were previously massless, acquire a mass.
$$
L=-\frac{1}{4} F_{\mu \nu}^a F^{a \mu \nu}+\left(D_\mu \Phi\right)^{\dagger}\left(D^\mu \Phi\right)-\lambda\left(\Phi^{\dagger} \Phi-\frac{v^2}{2}\right)^2, \\ \\ \Phi' = \Phi - v\sqrt2 (0 1).
$$
But in reality this is not the case, the two $W$'s and the $Z$ boson have different masses. Why don't I get that as a result here?  And what would I have to do to see that the three bosons have different masses?

The $U(1)$ is important in $SU(2) \times U(1)$.

Equivalently, the Z is not $W^3$, as per Glashow.
